# Objective-C Category does not get linked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, categories

I've got 2 categories for the same base class. One of them does get linked the other ones does not get linked. I get a runtime error with selector not found. (Using newest Xcode and iOS SDK.)

I've tried everything, so far to get it to work:

-ObjC (does not help though I leave it enabled of course)

-all_load (does not work since I have FMOD in my project which causes a ton of duplicate symbol errors then)

-force_load - I don't know how to use it properly. When using $(PRODUCTS_BUILD_DIR) it doesn't work on simulator since the path gets resolved to iphone-oes inside the products folder.

I also tried to include a dummy class in to my category but also that didn't help. I hope somebody has an idea for me what I could try to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem some time ago. It was caused by bad merge of project file: my category's implementation was not being added to valid target.

You can check if that's the case, especially since you mention that you have another category that works properly.

Comment: You made my day! That was correct. Even if the file compiled some time before and was added to the target it disappeared from the list for some reason.